# Osmdroid: How to create a Contextmenu next to a Marker?

Tags: android, contextmenu, osmdroid

My goal: i want to show a popupmenu next to a osmdroid-marker

My problem:

- In Android you can attach a android.widget.PopupMenu to a android.view.View : the menu is shown next to the view.
- In osmdroid a marker is inherited from org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay. Unfortunately Overlay is not inherited from View so i cannot attach a popup to it.

Currently i am attaching the menu to an image that is in the lower right corner but may be far away from the current marker.

This is my current code (from https://github.com/k3b/AndroFotoFinder/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/locationmap/LocationMapFragment.java )

```
public class LocationMapFragment extends DialogFragment {
    ...
    protected   boolean showContextMenu(final View parent, final int markerId,
                                        final IGeoPoint geoPosition, final Object markerData) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();

        // currently the contextmenu is attached to some image "this.mImage" 
        // which does not correspont to "geoPosition"
        // How to create a temporary 1x1 view at "geoPosition" 
        // where i can attach the menu to?
        PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), this.mImage);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map_context, menu.getMenu());

        menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.cmd_gallery:
                        return showGallery(getiGeoPointById(markerId, geoPosition));
                    case R.id.cmd_zoom:
                        return zoomToFit(getiGeoPointById(markerId, geoPosition));
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        menu.show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

My question: is there a simple way to create a temporary 1x1 pixel window on top of my marker at `IGeoPoint geoPosition` where i can attach the popup to?

Or is there any other simple way to position the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OSMBonusPack Marker InfoWindow](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/InfoWindow.java) (Marker bubble).

You can get its view with infowindow.getView(), and this is a regular android.view.View.

You can design its layout to make it as small as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final solution. `createTempPopupParentMenuView(GeoPoint position)` contains the code extracted from `InfoWindow` to provide a view for the popupMenu at marker-position:

```
/** temporary 1x1 pix view where popup-menu is attached to */
private View tempPopupMenuParentView = null;

...

protected   boolean showContextMenu(final View parent, final int markerId,
                                    final IGeoPoint geoPosition, final Object markerData) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    mMapView.removeView(tempPopupMenuParentView);

    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), createTempPopupParentMenuView(new GeoPoint(geoPosition.getLatitudeE6(), geoPosition.getLongitudeE6())));

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map_context, menu.getMenu());

    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            mMapView.removeView(tempPopupMenuParentView);

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.cmd_gallery:
                    return showGallery(getiGeoPointById(markerId, geoPosition));
                case R.id.cmd_zoom:
                    return zoomToFit(getiGeoPointById(markerId, geoPosition));
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
    menu.show();
    return true;
}

// inspired by org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.InfoWindow
private View createTempPopupParentMenuView(GeoPoint position) {
    if (tempPopupMenuParentView != null) mMapView.removeView(tempPopupMenuParentView);
    tempPopupMenuParentView = new View(getActivity());
    MapView.LayoutParams lp = new MapView.LayoutParams(
            1,
            1,
            position, MapView.LayoutParams.CENTER,
            0, 0);
    tempPopupMenuParentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMapView.addView(tempPopupMenuParentView, lp);
    return tempPopupMenuParentView;
}
```

Tanks to @MKer who directed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Like MKer said you can use OSMBonusPack Marker InfoWindow and customize your own InfoWindow.
https://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/osmdroid-bonus-pack-markers-with-clickable-infowindows/